# Binding bootstrap 3.0 progress-bar in KnockoutJs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to bing a bootstrap's progress-bar in ko, but the values are not updated.

Doest it work with style binding like this?

```
<div class="progress">
  <div  data-bind="style:{width: correct}" 
     class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" 
     aria-valuemax="100" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any advice!

**EDIT:** Adding some information.

Model:

```
viewModel: function(params) {
            this.correct = params.correct;
            this.wrong = params.wrong;
        };
```

Use of the component:

```
<result-view params="correct: correctAnswers, wrong: wrongAnswers"></result-view>
```

where the variables are defined in main model as:

```
var MM = {
        correctAnswers: ko.observable(0),
        wrongAnswers: ko.observable(0)
};
```

The params-function is called (checked with alert()) and the values are sensible.

Comment: Take a look at [Knockstrap](http://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/) - designed to bridge the two together

Comment: The existence of such libs seems to be the evidence, that it is not that easy, right? I have actually checked this and some other BS/jQ, bindings-libs already. At this stage I'm trying to figure out, how KO works. As I'm very new to JS &Co, an additional library would confuse me completely. I wonder, if there is an error in my understanding or the code. Thank you anyway. At later time-point I'll take a look at a more convenient bindings-lib closely.

Comment: You can try with `data-bind="style:{width: correct() + '%'}"`

Comment: @nemesv: Great! It was not exactly the solution (using +'%' in this place seems to be not valid), but the missing % was the reason indeed. Now I've added to the model an additional variable providing the value of correctAnswers + '%' and it works. I wish, I could do it somehow more elegant, e.g. `this.correct = params.correct + '%';` in the param-function, but I cant figure out the right syntax. However, many thanks, it works now without additional libs. If you make your comment as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the error, thanks to nemesv!

The css width-attribute of bootstrap's progress-bar requires the percent-value.
I've extended my model with additional string variables providing the per-cent values:

```
var MM = {
    correctAnswers: ko.observable(0),
    correctAnswersPct: ko.observable("0%"),
    wrongAnswers: ko.observable(0),
    wrongAnswersPct: ko.observable("0%"),
};
```

and bind the component to them:

```
<result-view params="correct: correctAnswersPct, wrong: wrongAnswersPct"></result-view>
```

Now it works as expected.